# Xcode compiler problems

Tags: c, xcode

I've created a simple project in Xcode for experiments with algoritms, now I'm trying to implement mergesort.
The prototype of mergesort function is

```
//mergesort.h
void merge(long *left, long *right, int lsize, int rsize);
void mergesort(long *data, int datasize);
```

The implementation is

```
//mergesort.c
void merge(long *left, long *right, int lsize, int rsize){

int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;
long *temp = malloc(sizeof(long) * (rsize + lsize));

while(i < lsize && j < rsize){
    if(left[i] < right[j]){
        temp[k++] = left[i++];
    }else{
        temp[k++] = right[j++];
    }

    if(i == lsize){
        for(;j < rsize;){
            temp[k++] = right[j++];
        }
    }

    if(j == rsize){
        for(;i < lsize;){
            temp[k++] = left[i++];
        }
    }
}
memcpy(left, temp, sizeof(long) * (lsize + rsize));
free(temp);
}

void mergesort(long *data, int datasize){
    int lsize, rsize;
    lsize = datasize / 2;
    rsize = datasize - lsize;

    if(lsize  < 1 || rsize < 1){
        return;
    }else{
        mergesort(data, lsize);
        mergesort(data + lsize, rsize);
        merge(data, data + lsize, lsize, rsize);
    }
```

So problem is that I can't compile the code. I was wondered that compiler says: 
"Too few arguments to function call, expected 4, have 2" on calls of mergesort(), i.e. on 
mergesort(data, lsize);
mergesort(data + lsize, rsize);

Why is that? Is it strange feature of default xcode compilator or I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: What line are you getting the error on?

Comment: on line with recursion calls `mergesort(data, lsize);` `mergesort(data + lsize, rsize);`  and on first function call in main() body

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is almost certainly that the function `mergesort` is already defined in `<stdlib.h>` with the prototype:

```
int
 mergesort(void *base, size_t nel, size_t width,
     int (*compar)(const void *, const void *));
```

i.e. four arguments. So that has obviously created ambiguity wherever the failing call is.

Probably the safest thing to do is to rename your function.

Comment: Since this is in Xcode, you can test Tommy's hypothesis by command-clicking a call to mergesort in your code. This will open up the file where it is defined.

Comment: Thank you very much! I was confused because on my another computer with linux and gcc compiler were no problems